# Mocha doesn't call rmdir in after() function

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, mocha.js, rmdir

I try to create some tree of directories before tests and remove it after all:

```
require('should');
var fs = require('fs');
var rmdir = require('rmdir');

describe('FsWatcher', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    console.log("before");
    fs.mkdir('tmp');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/css');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/js');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/lib');
    fs.open('tmp/index.htm', 'w');
    // (...)
    console.log("after_before");
    done();
  });

  describe('single file', function() {
    it('should succed', function(done) {
      (1).should.equal(1);
      done();
    });
  });

  after(function() {
    console.log("after");
    rmdir('tmp', function() {
        console.log("rmdir!");
    });
    console.log("after_end");
  });
});
```

The order of `console.log`s is OK:

```
mocha `find tests -name '*.js'`

  before
after_before
․after
after_end


  ✔ 1 test complete (6 ms)
```

But it doesn't call rmdir(). The same rmdir works when it's at the end of `before()`:

```
describe('FsWatcher', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    console.log("before");
    fs.mkdir('tmp');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/css');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/js');
    fs.mkdir('tmp/lib');
    fs.open('tmp/index.htm', 'w');
    // (...)
    console.log("after_before");
    rmdir('tmp', function(){
        console.log("rmdir!");
    });
    done();
  });
});
```

Console:

```
mocha `find tests -name '*.js'`

  before
after_before
 rmdir!
after
after_end
```

Why it doesn't work in the `after()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The test finishes too fast.  You need to use the asynchronous version of after.

```
after(function(done) {
    console.log("after");
    rmdir('tmp', function() {
        console.log("rmdir!");
        done();
    });
    console.log("after_end");
});
```

Which should output:

```
 after
 after_end
 rmdir!
```

The reason it appears to work when you call it from `before()`, is because there are plenty of other things happening, so rmdir will get called, but later when node goes back to the event loop.